# Generate token in rest java api

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, jwt, token

I have a Java Restful api (I use JAX-RS) and I need to create a post method that returns a token.

However my method is giving exception in the method 'gerarToken'

Can anybody help me?
Follow below code

```
@POST
@Path("/login")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response fazerLogin(String credenciais) {
    try {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        UsuarioTO u = gson.fromJson(credenciais, UsuarioTO.class);
        validarCrendenciais(u);
        String token = gerarToken(u.getLogin(), 1);
        return Response.ok(token).build();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).build();
    }
}

private String gerarToken(String login,Integer expiraEmDias ){
    SignatureAlgorithm algoritimoAssinatura = SignatureAlgorithm.HS512;
    Date agora = new Date();
    Calendar expira = Calendar.getInstance();
    expira.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, expiraEmDias);
    byte[] apiKeySecretBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary("E5c0l4r");
    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(apiKeySecretBytes, algoritimoAssinatura.getJcaName());
    JwtBuilder construtor = Jwts.builder()
                                .setIssuedAt(agora)
                                .setSubject(login)
                                .setIssuer(login)
                                .setWith(algoritimoAssinatura,key)   
                                .setExpiration(expira.getTime());

    return construtor.compact();

}
```

In 'Jwts.builder' throw that exception
    The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
    java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: USE_DEFAULTS
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude$Value.(JsonInclude.java:204)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.cfg.MapperConfig.(MapperConfig.java:44)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.(ObjectMapper.java:549)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.(ObjectMapper.java:465)
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtBuilder.(DefaultJwtBuilder.java:42)
    at io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts.builder(Jwts.java:116)
    at br.gov.es.dataci.aprender.controleacesso.ControleAcesso.gerarToken(ControleAcesso.java:85)
    at br.gov.es.dataci.aprender.controleacesso.ControleAcesso.fazerLogin(ControleAcesso.java:46)

Comment: NoSuchFieldError indicates that you're using incompatible libraries. Some library references the field USE_DEFAULTS, which doesn't exist in your version of the library. Check your dependencies, their docmentation and pom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

It was giving the method error because of the wrong version of the jackson.annotations library.

I changed it to version 2.8